# How to insert a record in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to insert a record in MVC4 with Entity Framework?

here is my viewpage:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.brand_id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.brand_name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("ADD", "BrandList", new { item.brand_id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

here is my controller code:

```
        public ActionResult BrandList()
        {
            return View(db.brand.ToList());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult BrandList(int id)
        {
            lovelist Add_Brand = new lovelist();
            Add_Brand.lovelist_member = (int)Session["Member_ID"];
            Add_Brand.lovelist_brand = id;
            db.lovelist.Add(Add_Brand);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("BrandList");
        }
```

This is what I did so far.

I cannot insert a record to my DB.

**There's no any error message. I still cannt insert a record to my DB.**

Comment: parameter names should match.check rameshrams answer

Comment: Do you have an error message or any thing?

Comment: @wilsjd There's no any error message. I still cannot insert a record to my DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 actions on your controller called `BrandList`. The second is decorated with the `[HttpPost]` attribute meaning that it can only be invoked using the POST verb. But in the code you have shown you have only a hyperlink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("ADD", "BrandList", new { item.brand_id })
```

In HTML a hyperlink (anchor) sends GET request. So basically when you click on this link you are invoking the first action which doesn't do any DB saving. If you wanted to invoke the second action using a hyperlink you should rename it (because you cannot have 2 actions with the same name accessible with the same verb) and remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute from it:

```
public ActionResult SaveBrandList(int id)
{
    lovelist Add_Brand = new lovelist();
    Add_Brand.lovelist_member = (int)Session["Member_ID"];
    Add_Brand.lovelist_brand = id;
    db.lovelist.Add(Add_Brand);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("BrandList");    
}
```

You will obviously need to adapt your view as well:

```
@Html.ActionLink("ADD", "SaveBrandList", new { item.brand_id })
```

---

There's also a possibility to use an AJAX link which would allow you to send a POST request:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("ADD", "BrandList", new { item.brand_id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })
```

You will need to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script in your view for this to work. Also since you are using an AJAX call now, there's no need to be redirecting anymore from your POST controller action but simply return some partial view or JSON that could be used on the client to refresh some portion of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed parameter name in id and controllername . please change your action-link  to

```
 @Html.ActionLink("ADD", "BrandList","ControllerName", new {id = item.brand_id })
```

Comment: The ControllerName is optional if both views are in the same controller.

Comment: both views are in the same controller.
I still cannot insert a record to my DB.